# How can I use Hibernate Criteria's to query nested tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, associations, criteria

I've looked all over SO and Google but I guess I'm not using the right search terms or something.

Anyway, say I have three tables:

```
Companies
-----------------------------------------
id
name
user_id

Users
-----------------------------------------
id
username
usertype_id

UserTypes
-----------------------------------------
id
typeofuser
```

So `ACME` would be a company, it would have a user `Moe` and Moe would be a usertype of `Stooge`.

In SQL, I would do something like:

```
select
    *
from companies c
    join users u on (u.id = c.user_id)
    join usertypes ut on (ut.id = u.usertype_id)
where
    ut.typeofuser = 'Stooge'
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do that in a Criteria.  I have tried:

```
Criteria crit = io.getSession().createCriteria(Company.class);
List<Company> list = 
    crit.createCriteria("users")
        .createCriteria("usertypes")
            .add(Restriction.eq("typeofuser", "Stooge").list();
```

But I get back way too many records. And the results don't even come close to being accurate.

I've also tried:

```
Criteria crit = io.getSession().createCriteria(Company.class);
List<Company> list = 
    crit.createAlias("users", "u")
        .createAlias("u.usertypes", "ut")
            .add(Restriction.eq("ut.typeofuser", "Stooge").list();
```

Seems to bring back the exact same result set.  I actually have read the user manual.  And when I nest only one level deep (ie, searching by users is fine) but when I get two layers deep, I can't quite get it.  And the manual is no help.  I just can't relate cats and kittens to business objects.  Maybe they should use cats, kittens and fleas?  :-/

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While your query should work, below is another variation:

```
 Criteria crit = io.getSession().createCriteria(Company.class);
 List<Company> list = 
       crit.createAlias("users", "u")
       .createAlias("u.usertypes", "ut", Criteria.INNER_JOIN, 
                         Restrictions.eq("ut.typeofuser", "Stooge")
       .list();
```

Comment: thanX a lot, your answer save me lots of time !

Comment: Which would be more efficient? INNER_JOIN or add?

Comment: I don't think there is a straight answer for that. If tables have limited data and inner join filters the unwanted data upfront, it's going to be efficient; otherwise we need to work on/fine tune filter conditions to result in optimal data need/manipulation in the memory. We can also optimize the database configs using indexes, partitions and other query optimizing techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I was doing it right all along.  I had an error somewhere else.

Feel free to delete this question.