# Insanely difficult hibernate query for nested tables

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

Ok so my problem is very similar to the following question: [How can I use Hibernate Criteria's to query nested tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316992/how-can-i-use-hibernate-criterias-to-query-nested-tables)

But the solutions they provided don't work for me, even though it seems to be the exact same thing. What am I doing differently?

Here is my specific problem:

I have 3 tables:

```
COURSE
-----------------------------------------
uid
name
course_catalog_uid

COURSE_CATALOG
-----------------------------------------
uid
name
product_type_uid

PRODUCT_TYPE
-----------------------------------------
uid
name
```

I have either 1 or 2 product_type_uid's and I need to get a list of COURSE's where the (drilling down the nested tables) the PRODUCT_TYPE.uid = either of the 2 initial values that I provide.

I have been googling for 3 hours now and nothing I have found works. I would really appreciate any help I can get. I am exhausted and it's almost COB. I will check/comment on all responses first thing tomorrow morning.

Also just in case:
I am working on a Java EE web application which runs on WAS (using java 1.7)

Edit: with regards to the related question I linked to, their solution did not even work if I provide just one product_type_uid. Here is my code:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Course.class);
List<Course> list = crit.createAlias("course_catalog", "cclog")
.createAlias("cclog.product_type_uid", "ptypeuid", 
Criteria.INNER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("ptypeuid", ptype.getUid()).list();
```

This produces the following error when I run it:

```
[12/9/14 7:53:47:294 SAST] 000002fd LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[12/9/14 7:53:47:294 SAST] 000002fd webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[/operations/operationshome.jsp]: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: course_catalog of: com.companyname.model.Course
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
```

So "org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: course_catalog"

I'm guessing that means there's no course_catalog field in my course table (which there isn't)
But how do I link the different tables accross my query?

Comment: Hibernate maps to fields not methods so this `Restrictions.eq("ptype.getUid()", ptype.getUid())` is not right. Did you mean `Restrictions.eq("ptypeuid", ptype.getUid())`?

Comment: Thanks. That was just a stupid mistake, but still doesn't work.

I'll update my question to show the new changes.

Comment: One thing I find that helps on complex queries is to write the query I want with SQL, then HQL then see if I can get it to map to a criteria. If you can't you can still use HQL and build the objects yourself or have Hibernate do it by calling addEntity(). Sometimes you can't avoid HQL. Even the creator of Hibernate says you can't do everything with Hibernate.

Comment: Using addEntity with HQL can take a very long time since Hibernate resolves all other objects, not just the one you need so mapping it yourself can give you a lot more speed for a little more work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you map some POJO's to these tables?
What I would do is:

1. Create class Course with an attribute of type CourseCatalog which in turn has an attribute of type ProductType.
2. Map these classes to the database.  If it is a legacy database than adapt the table and column names in the mapping (annotations or hbm).  If not than just let hibernate generating the tables.
3. To get a Course instance with related objects just perform a get(Class, id) on the hibernate session instance.  Do not forget to disable the lazy behaviour if you want the child objects being loaded at first.

Comment: I've already done this. Please could you give a code example.